# ¿Cómo transformar una columna de formato string a numero en pandas de python?

Tags: python

Tengo un `dataframe` para trabajar pero la columna edad esta registrada como un `string`, la cual posee las edades de la siguiente forma "17" por lo cuando cuando quiero acceder al dato, obtengo el siguiente valor `' "17" '`, y necesito transformar la columna en `números`, alguien me podría guiar en como hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente Pandas detecta cuando una columna, a pesar de ser cadenas, representa un número y lo convierte automáticamente. Creo que en tu caso puede ser porque el número está encerrado a su vez en comillas tipográficas por lo que Pandas no lo ha convertido y lo ha dejado como cadena.

El problema en este caso es que un intento de aplicar `int()` sobre esa cadena fallará también debido a las comillas. Creo que lo más sencillo aquí sería usar una expresión regular tipo `\d+` para extraer lo que son los dígitos y luego aplicar `int()` sobre el resultado. Estoy suponiendo en este caso que todas las cantidades son enteras.

Por ejemplo, si tu dataframe es este:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Nombre": ["Alicia", "Bob", "Carlos"],
    "Edad":   ['" 19 "', '“ 17 ”', '“ 15 ”']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Nombre    Edad
0  Alicia  " 19 "
1     Bob  “ 17 ”
2  Carlos  “ 15 ”
```

Podrías arreglar esa columna edad de la siguiente forma:

```
import re

df.Edad = df.Edad.map(lambda x: int(re.search(r"\d+", x).group(0)))
```

Y ahora `df` quedaría así:

```
   Nombre  Edad
0  Alicia    19
1     Bob    17
2  Carlos    15
```

### Explicación

Mediante `df.Edad` accedemos a la columna `Edad`. Usando `.map()` sobre esa columna, se ejecutará una función para cada uno de sus elementos y se irán recogiendo los resultados retornados por esa función para crear una nueva columna con ellos, que en este caso es asignada de nuevo a `df.Edad`.

La función que `map()` ejecuta sobre cada elemento es la que le pasemos como parámetro. En este caso le paso una `lambda x:` que es una función que voy a definir ahí mismo, que recibirá como parámetro `x`. Este parámetro será un valor de la columna, en nuestro caso una de esas cadenas que tiene números.

Mediante `re.search(r"\d+", x)` buscamos en la cadena `x` la parte que encaje con la expresión regular `\d+`, que significa "una secuencia de uno o más dígitos seguidos". El resultado que devuelve `re.search()` es de tipo *match*, un tipo que tiene el método `.group()` para acceder a los grupos de resultados. En este caso `.group(0)` tendrá todo el texto que haya encajado con la expresión regular, es decir, justo la secuencia de dígitos que buscábamos.

Ese resultado se pasa a la función `int()`, para que lo convierta e entero. Y eso es lo que retorna finalmente como resultado nuestra lambda.

Ya que la `map()` aplica esa función lambda a cada elemento de la columna, al final tenemos todos convertidos a entero.

**Nota**. El código fallará si algún elemento de la columna no contiene un patrón de dígitos. También fallará si el número contiene puntos o comas decimales.

Comment: Increible, me sirivio, muchas gracias por tu gran explicacion! fue justo lo que me pasaba con int()

Answer (score -1):

Prueba hacer un cast cuando quieres recoger el dato ejemplo: `int_Edad=int("17")` en este caso le dices que el dato es de tipo `int` con esto no creo que tengas ningún problema.